# Who is Lucinda Walters' mother?

Tags: dc, batman-beyond

In the [Batman Beyond Unlimited issue #3](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_Beyond_Unlimited_Vol_1_3) ("Superman Beyond, Part I") it is revealed

[image]

> That a woman with a keen mind for electronics is informed she is the daughter of Lex Luthor.

I'm wondering if the name Walters is someone who already exists in the DC Universe as the possible mother. Is this someone who previously had associations with the father, or an entirely new character created for the Unlimited universe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, her mother (presumably pictured left) is an unknown character invented solely for the '[Superman : Beyond](http://www.supermanhomepage.com/comics/comics-index-lists/comics-supermanbeyond-intro.php?topic=comics-supermanbeyond-2012)' series of comics. Her romantic encounter/s with Lex aren't related in any great detail, nor is she named in the comics I've read. She dies some three years before the events of Superman : Beyond.

From the info contained in the subsequent episodes, it seems that while Lex was aware of her existence, he made no attempt to contact her through her mother other than by giving her a card to place in her safety deposit box.

[image: Lucinda Luthor]